# IBM Maximo Lookup selecting another value not default value

Tags: maximo

I am trying to create a lookup. I want to select from PERSON table - if I select a value through lookup, person id is selected, but I need display name value. I have tried by creating a table domain, lookup table, lookup.XML and all methods.

Comment: Question is unclear as to what kind of results you want. Perhaps including more details or a screenshot describing how you want the display name to show up would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the DisplayName *copied* to the local object *in addition to* the PersonID, then instead of a Table Domain, you need a Crossover Domain with DisplayName as a Source Field and with your local attribute that should hold the copy of Person.DisplayName as the Target Field.

If you need the DisplayName *copied* to the local object *instead of* the PersonID, then you'll need to make a lookup map on the target attribute so Maximo knows what attribute returned by the domain maps to which attribute on the local object. You set Lookup Maps with the little, white, "page" icon/button on the right side of the Attributes tab in Database Configuration for the desired target attribute.

If you just need to *see* the DisplayName once a PersonID is selected, then use a Mulitpart Textbox and set "Attribute for Part 2" to something like PERSON.DISPLAYNAME, where PERSON is the name of the relationship from the local object to the PERSON object.

Answer (score 0):

As Preacher already mentioned, you can copy the DISPLAYNAME attribute using a lookup map - on the Database Configuration application, go to the attribute to which you want to copy - probably the one, where you used the table domain on - and click the [image] icon.

If you have created a custom field and have no Java class on it, you will still need the table domain, so leave that on the attribute. Now, on the lookup map, you can define which fields you want to copy from the source MBO to the target MBO. You can define multiple target fields from here (so no need to define a crossover domain, even if you need to copy multiple fields) - just enter a new line for any field you want to copy from the source (Person) object.

On many versions of Maximo you will have to restart before this starts working! I believe you don't have to restart on 7.6, but on any previous version you will probably have to.

Now, about the definition in lookups.XML: if you want to show different attributes than the ones, already shown on the default "person" lookup, you need to define your own, as you did. If the default one looks fine, for you, you can just use "person" as the lookup, since the logic of copying fields is defined in the lookup map, not in lookups.XML.